# Problems with designing of the database schema

Tags: database-design, uml, database-schema, entity-relationship, erd

Developers and Database Designers, hi!

I design a database schema to my project.

The project involves the relationships between 'Producers' and 'Consumers'. But if a 'Producer' may be both a 'User' and an 'Organization', then a 'Consumer' may be only a 'User' (although it is only just now). If to consider the object model of my project, it mainly consists of two basic interfaces - 'Producers' and 'Consumers'. The relationships will be between instances of the main classes that is 'Organization' and 'User', what is more 'Organization' class implements the 'Producer' interface and 'User' class implements the interfaces of 'Producer' and 'Сonsumer'. For example, for a certain period of using my application some users must be able to sell items to other users, and be able to buy goods from anyone.

[image]

In the future, I am planning to integrate the most demanded payment systems to the project. Tell me please if you have experience of working with payment systems, how it will change the model and database schema. Do I need to add the entities of 'Legal entity' and 'Individual'?

I designed the ER-diagram according to the description above, but it has several drawbacks.

[image]

Firstly, there is no complete correspondence between ER-description and UML description. Do I need to allocate detached tables for interfaces? I do not know. Indeed, in this case, according to the ER-description it can be said that the 'Producer' and 'Consumer' are superclasses of 'Organization' and 'User'. But in fact they are only interfaces.

Secondly, I need the simpliest designing to provide the access to the storage sufficiently flexible, without unnecessary 'JOIN's. Maybe I should completely abandon the interfaces implementations? But I'm all for using OOP wealth. Is it possible to use interfaces implementations at the database level? I know that inheritance can be used. But I do not know how these tricks will affect the productivity - because of all previous projects did not require the using of the superclasses and interfaces. I will use PostgreSQL as a relational DBMS.

Please share your experience and implementations of successful database schemes.

**UPDATE**

If I will assign roles for tables 'Producer' and 'Consumer', then I'll have to give them attributes characterizing entities 'User' and 'Organization'. On the one hand, if the number of roles increases, then the number of attributes increases. This path entails congestion of the tables' attributes. And some attributes for different roles will conform to NULL values. On the other hand, one attribute for a one role can conform to multiple attributes for another role. For example, the attribute 'name' for an entity 'Organization' conform to the attributes 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname' and 'username' for an entity 'User'. Thirdly, I still want to separate models 'Producer', 'Organization', 'User' and 'Consumer'  from each other.

[image]

Comment: What I think you are struggling with is the topic of "roles". It's a very common problem. A person can play many roles. That does not make a person a kind of a role because that means it must always be the case. You may find that creating a role-playing relation can solve the problem, but I haven't had time to analyze your problem carefully. You may also find that qua entities (e.g., person as producer) are helpful for maintaining history and other facts.

Comment: Tricky, indeed. What Jim says is right. I might look into this later the evening (unless Jim provides a good answer).

Comment: I think you are asking too many questions at once, actually. I count four explicit questions and several more implicit questions. Everything stems from an inaccurate model of what exists in the problem domain. I suggest you fix that problem. The UML and ER can then both easily align with that. In fact, one UML model can provide the basis for your OOP and your DB.

Comment: Totally agree with Jim. "In the future, I am planning..." is a whole new story. You might ask that as separate question but has chances to get closed as too broad. Just give it a try. I'll now think over your Firstly and Secondly (where I think that the latter is also another story; so hope for an answer to Firstly).

Comment: Thank you for your objective comments. My "In the future, I am planning ..." refers to the fact that the model should be prepared for such designing in advance. And I think that it is better to design a model with considering of the suggestions. Role descriptor appears always when roles are used. And often we have the following picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYFNZ.png
I added it to **UPDATE** section of my question.

Comment: Your update makes no sense to me. This is not the forum for back and forth lessons on how to do analysis and design. Please ask a new, straightforward question that doesn't require a book chapter in response.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways and none is an optimum. So as an architect you need to weigh the different pros and cons of an architecture. I would probably start with building a database abstraction. Here it depends on how much you would need persistence of your objects. That is, do I need instant persistence or would it be good enough to have some shadowing which can work in the background.

[image]

So basically you have tables which depend on the corresponding classes. You could simply leave it open how this dependency is realized. Certain programming languages provide scaffolding to map one against the other. This is convenient and saves a lot of typing/design. Of course it's not very flexible. So based on this you should consider various options. Would it be necessary to implement database access inside the classes and have them realize some serializer interface?

[image]

That would definitely offer a lot of tweaking and performance options. But likely you also will have some implementation overhead.

Or would it be better to have some shadowing mechanism where you can subscribe to have your state be saved concurrently?

[image]

So, in order to get the right design decision you need to think about how objects and database are related to each other and how strong this binding needs to be. Unfortunately there is no silver bullet.